# Discrod.js requestManager is undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When I try to run the bot, it throws this error:

> this.rest.requestManager.clearHashSweeper();                            ^
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clearHashSweeper')

But if I disable IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent and IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers then everything works, how to fix this problem?

```
const bot = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers
  ],
  rest: {
    version: '10'
  }
});
```

discord.js: 14.12.0

node: 18.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rest property from your client and it should work. Theres also a comma missing after the GuildMessages intent.

```js
const bot = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could stem from not having the correct permissions in the [developer/application portal](https://discord.com/developers/)

It fails silently it seems and cascades into a "clearHashSweeper" issue. I was having this problem as well, this just resolved it. Also keep in mind, in your example you require one comma which is missing.